# Vuejs - get position on array

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have an array of objects. I need to get the positions of the array where the condition is met, as below:

Array
(3) [{word[0]}, {word[1]}, {word[2]}, **ob**: Observer]

when word.lenght > 0 - I need all the positions that meet this condition.

in this example would return me positions 1 and 2 of the array

Comment: This sounds like an XY problem (http://xyproblem.info/) - mind adding code and expected outcome?

Answer (score 0):

```js
const words = ['', 'a', 'ab'];
const positions = words.reduce((acc, word, index) => {
  if (word.length > 0) {
    acc.push(index);
  }
  return acc; }, []);
window.alert(positions);
```